# How can I decrypt a password in SFTP file downloading from java

Tags: java

I have written a java code to download file from remote machine to my local machine via SFTP.

So the connectivity I have used these parameters:

```
sftpBean.connect(HOSTIP, Port, Username,Password);
```

But now here password will be in Encrypted format so what can I write to decrypt the password.

Comment: How will your password be encrypted? Which algo?

Comment: the client will give us encrypted password

Comment: _the client will give us encrypted password_ - the password is encrypted using an algorithm and a key; you need to know these, then you can use the classes from the [javax.crypto](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-sec1/j-sec1.html) library to decrypt the password.

Comment: And of course once the client has provided you with all that, there isn't all that much point in the client encrypting the password in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways (algorithms, modes, ..) how to encrypt a password.

So - this API (sftpBean) needs a cleartext password. As Jozef stated in the comment - if the client provides out an encrypted password, the client has to provide you means to get the cleartext form (at least information how to decrypt it, algorithm and parameters used).

Once you have these information, you may ask another question with details (without providing the real password/key) if you are blocked.

Comment: Thanks i will ask them.